# How to select first and last rows of each unique records in pandas

Tags: python

How do I select first and last rows of all the unique records.

I tried below code but I know it's not correct. First it takes only one column and others are missed in this one.

```
for key, value in df['x'].iteritems():
    # print(key, value)
    if temp != value:
        print(temp)
    temp = value
```

[Expected output records are highlighted in yellow in the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/804pg.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of posting an image, please upload a dataset in code so others can reproduce. Also, please provide an expect output :)

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here, if a record is truly unique wouldn't the first and last row of those be the same? Are you looking for the index of the first and last rows of a group of duplicate rows?

Comment: I am sry my question is confusing. Its a time series record of different cases. I need first and last record of each case. Every case has unique number which is the column 'x'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: After understanding OP's question better, I think I've come up with the proper solution

The initial table

```
+----------------+
|x         |y |z |
+----------------+
|111000004 |1 |1 |
|111000014 |5 |1 |
|111000014 |5 |2 |
|111001605 |2 |1 |
|111001605 |2 |2 |
|111003425 |1 |1 |
|111003425 |1 |2 |
|111003425 |1 |3 |
|111003748 |4 |1 |
|111003748 |4 |2 |
|111003748 |3 |4 |
|111003748 |2 |3 |
|111003748 |1 |1 |
+----------------+
```

OP mentioned it was a time-series data, so I grouped the data by the time column ("x") and got the first and last row. I appended the two tables and sorted them by the index ("x") and removed duplicates to clean up the output.

```
g = df.groupby(['x'])
d = g.first().append(g.last()).sort_index().reset_index().drop_duplicates()
```

The final result is in `d` as follows.

```
+----------------+
|x         |y |z |
+----------------+
|111000004 |1 |1 |
|111000014 |5 |1 |
|111000014 |5 |2 |
|111001605 |2 |1 |
|111001605 |2 |2 |
|111003425 |1 |1 |
|111003425 |1 |3 |
|111003748 |4 |1 |
|111003748 |1 |1 |
+----------------+
```

---

To get all unique rows in a DataFrame, you can do this

```
unique_df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Then to get the first and last row you can call `head()` and `tail()` on the `unique_df`

```
first = unique_df.head(1)
last = unique_df.tail(1)
```

Comment: If we drop duplicates then all the rows will be unique then there is no point of having first or last row of each unique record. I think the question itself is not clear

Comment: Ah I see. I misunderstood when OP said "select first and last rows of all the unique records"

Comment: I am a Java guy and did this with 100 lines of codes yesterday. But you did exactly what I wanted in just 2 lines of codes :). Thanks cybergla, u r a legend. Sry for not posting a clear question.

Comment: No worries :) Glad I was able to help.